# Connect to RabbitMQ without sending plain text password

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq

I understand it is possible to connect to RabbitMQ for sending/receiving messages using LDAP or SSL without specifying plain text password. I just wonder is there any other way to achieve? we really dont want to specify the plain text password for security reasons.

```
 var connectionFactory = new RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory()
        {
            UserName = "guest",
            Password = "guest", //not preferred
            HostName = "localhost"
        };
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to achieve.  Are you saying you want to use an encrypted password or you want to omit the password requirement altogether?  Subsequently, why?

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Why do you think the password is sent across the wire without ssl/tls?

Comment: @DavidL, I'm just trying to find out the way to not to specify the plain text password in the code.

Comment: Ahh, got it.  That's a very different question.  Typically you would load passwords from configuration.  The password could be stored at rest in the configuration file in an encrypted form that you decrypt before instantiating your connection.  You could also use something like Azure App Configuration and Azure Key Vault to store secrets away from the machine altogether.